# Accessing WP core with my PHP script

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a script that would download and install wordpress + plugins + themes automatically.

All the stages until installing are working out. The files are downloaded and the wp-config.php is working - but when I try to run the wp install I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::add_query_var() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\wp\wp\wp-includes\taxonomy.php on line 371

From doing some research - it seems that the problem is finding the right way to include wordpress functions in my script - this is my code

```
define( 'WP_INSTALLING', true );
global $wp;
require_once( $directory . 'wp-blog-header.php' );
/** Load WordPress Bootstrap */
require_once( $directory . 'wp-load.php' );

/** Load WordPress Administration Upgrade API */
require_once( $directory . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

/** Load wpdb */
require_once( $directory . 'wp-includes/wp-db.php' );

var_dump($wp);
// WordPress installation
wp_install( $data[ 'weblog_title' ], $data['user_login'], $data['admin_email'], (int) $data[ 'blog_public' ], '', $data['admin_password'] );
```

in taxonomy line 371 theres a function call :

```
$wp->add_query_var( $args['query_var'] );
```

I suspect that $wp never gets defined.
Does anyone know what I should change to do that?

I made sure that it crashes on the wp_install - never goes past that in my script.

Comment: This may be helpful: [WP-Quick-Install](https://github.com/GeekPress/WP-Quick-Install)

Comment: I'm actually using this as a base - and I noticed something interesting - they call their script in two different ways

normally they do :
/index.php?action=unzip_wp (or a different action)

but when they call the wp install they do :

/index.php/wp-admin/install.php?action=install_wp

when I changed their script to have all the calls the same it stopped functioning as well!
isn't that weird?   Problem is, I don't want to use js at all.